# How to check if alert has been called?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, spyon

I am testing my Angular application, I currently I want to check if alert has showed up after clicking on a button. I have the following code:

```
it('should display alert when clicking on icon', () => {
  const button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.pi-trash');
  button.click();
  spyOn(window, 'alert').and.callThrough();
  expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('delete');
})
```

An alert is created with a message 'delete' and in the logs I can see: "ALERT: delete", but test is failing with an error:
Expected spy alert to have been called with:
[ 'delete' ]
but it was never called.

Can someone tell me what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you just try to move `spyOn(window, 'alert').and.callThrough();` to the beginning of the test. I assume that in your case `window.alert` was only spied on after it was already called.

Comment: Yeah, that was it... Stupid mistake, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this question can be closed successfully. Here is the answer:
`spyOn(window, 'alert').and.callThrough();` has to be moved to the beginning of the test. In your case `window.alert` was only spied on after it was already called.